# Update four links in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to update four links in a workbook that I have created. I have pieced together the following code using what I found online. The links that I am trying to replace have dynamic file names based on date and state. I was hoping that excel orders link names the same way they are ordered in the edit links window. It appears this is not the case.

The issue I am having is that the link that I intended to be varlink(1) is being replaced by the one that is meant to replace varlink(4). Is there anyway to ensure I replace the "loss" link with the "loss" link, etc.?

```
Sub UpDateLinks()

Dim Date1 As String
Dim StateAbbrev As Variant
Dim varLinks As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Inputs").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("StateAbbrev").Activate
StateAbbrev = ActiveCell.Value
Date1 = Range("AD1")

varLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink _
            Name:=varLinks(1), NewName:="F:\MyHouse\" & Date1 & "\" & StateAbbrev & "\Home\" & StateAbbrev & " Loss Trends " & Date1 & ".xlsm", _
            Type:=xlExcelLinks

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink _
            Name:=varLinks(2), NewName:="F:\MyHouse\" & Date1 & "\" & StateAbbrev & "\Home\" & StateAbbrev & " Prem Trends " & Date1 & ".xlsm", _
            Type:=xlExcelLinks

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink _
            Name:=varLinks(3), NewName:="F:\MyHouse\" & Date1 & "\" & StateAbbrev & "\Home\" & StateAbbrev & " Fast Track Loss Trends " & Date1 & ".xlsm", _
            Type:=xlExcelLinks

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink _
            Name:=varLinks(4), NewName:="F:\MyHouse\" & Date1 & "\Home\" & StateAbbrev & " Section A " & Date1 & "-Revised.xlsx", _
            Type:=xlExcelLinks

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loop through each of the links and use a `Select Case` to determine which link you are working with, you can then determine the right link to change.

See the code below that I modified based on what you have in your OP.

```
Sub UpDateLinks()

Dim Date1 As String
Dim StateAbbrev As String, sLink As String, sNewName as String
Dim varLinks As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Inputs")

With ws

    StateAbbrev = .Range("StateAbbrev")
    Date1 = .Range("AD1")

End With

varLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)

For i = 1 To UBound(varLinks)

    Dim x As Integer
    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "Loss Trends") Then sLink = "Loss Trends"
    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "Prem Trends") Then sLink = "Prem Trends"
    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "Fast Track Loss Trends") Then sLink = "Fast Track Loss Trends"
    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "Section A") Then sLink = "Section A"

    sNewName = "F:\MyHouse\" & Date1 & "\" & StateAbbrev & "\Home\" & StateAbbrev & " " & sLink & " " & Date1 & ".xlsm"

    If sLink = "Section A" Then sNewName = Replace(sNewName,".xlsm","-Revised.xlsm")         

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink _
            Name:=varLinks(i), NewName:=sNewName, Type:=xlExcelLInks

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt and thorough reponse! That worked perfectly. It required a few quick edits, but was exactly what I needed! Thanks again.

Comment: I just realized some of it superfluous. You can remove the whole `Select Case` and just set `sLink` after the `Then` of the each `If` statement. Will make it shorter code and easier to read.

Comment: I just saw another way to make cleaner and easier to read, in terms of naming the file. I guess I was a bit bored at the moment :)